# update to play-services-cast-framework:17.1.0 adds old protobuf dependency, causes conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cast

Following the advice from https://developers.google.com/cast/support, I'm posting this question.

I've developed an Android app that integrates Google Cast functionality. My app also uses protobuf-java:3.9.1 to implement part of its functionality.

This weekend I decided to update the app's dependencies. The app built and worked just fine prior to my attempt to update the dependencies.

I was previously using play-services-cast-framework:17.0.0, and updated this to 17.1.0. When I did this I picked up a transitive dependency on protobuf-lite:3.0.1, which contains classes that conflict with protobuf-java:3.9.1 causing the build to fail.

My question: Is this new dependency on an old version of protobuf a bug introduced in play-services-cast-framework:17.1.0?

Excerpt from the build error messages:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.9.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.9.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.9.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.9.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
...
```

There are several more duplicate class errors, which I've omitted.

As reported by the androidDependencies gradle task, when I use cast framework 17.1.0, I pick up the following new dependencies that are not present when I used cast frameworkd 17.0.0:

```
...
+--- com.google.android.datatransport:transport-backend-cct:2.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:2.0.0@aar
...
+--- com.google.android.datatransport:transport-api:2.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22@jar
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar
+--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1@jar
...
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'd like to be using the latest cast framework, but not if I have to give up the latest protobuf.

Comment: This is still a problem with cast framework 18.0.0. :(

Comment: Seems to be resolved with cast framework 20.0.0.